# Remove selected whitespaces from string in R

Tags: string, rstudio, str-replace, gsub, stringr

I am really stuck at some point by trying to get rid of some whitespaces in my character string that I obtained from a PDF.

The string looks as follows:

```
[1] "                                      ZUSAMMEN          8 756    3 193       1 456        531         506       1 931    1 780        225      2 059"
```

As you can see, the problem that I have is that all the "thousands" are separated with a whitespace, that is instead of 8756, it is 8 756.

My problem is that I want to automatically remove only the whitespace between the thousands.

I know how to manage this manually, but I need an automated way because I have a couple of thousand observations to adjust.

What I tried was:

```
c <- gsub("\\s", "", t)
```

revealing

```
[1] "ZUSAMMEN875631931456531506193117802252059"
```

However, I don't know how to only get rid of those whitespaces that are inbetween the digits of the thousands.

I hope everything is clear!
Thanks in advance,
Niklas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
x <- "                                      ZUSAMMEN          8 756    3 193       1 456        531         506       1 931    1 780        225      2 059"
gsub("(\\d) (\\d)", "\\1\\2", x)
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/M3l5FS).

To remove any whitespace, use either of the two below:

```
gsub("(\\d)[[:space:]](\\d)", "\\1\\2", x)
gsub("(\\d)\\s(\\d)", "\\1\\2", x)
gsub("(*UCP)(\\d)\\s(\\d)", "\\1\\2", x, perl=TRUE)
gsub("(*UCP)(?<=\\d)\\s(?=\\d)", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

**Notes**

- `(\\d) (\\d)` matches and captures a digit into Capturing group 1 (with the first `(\\d)`), then matches a single space, and then captures into Group 2 another digit. The digits that were captured and consumed will be removed if their corresponding backreferences are not used in the replacement pattern, hence the `"\\1\\2"` replacement string contains them
- `[[:space:]]` is a POSIX character class that matches any whitespace, similar to `\s`
- If you work with Unicode texts, a PCRE regex (enabled with `perl=TRUE`) can be used with `\s` and `(*UCP)` verb (it will match soft/hard spaces, etc.)
- If you use `(?<=\\d)` lookbehind and `(?=\\d)` lookahead instead of capturing groups, the texts are not consumed (not added to match values) and are not thus removed, hence, no need in backreferences in the replacement pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly fine!!! Could you please explain the logic behind? I am rather new to R and would be interested in the logic behind.